# Retrieve data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three tables pedidos and pro_pedidos and logos.
i am trying to get data from pedidos where numero.pedidos=nuumero.prod_pedidos. and from logos i just want columns data. this query works without any error but display nothing but i have data behind in table  ?

```
SELECT a.id, a.numero, a.nome, a.codigo, a.fantasia, a.cnpj, a.endereco,
a.telefone, a.uf, a.cidade, a.cep, a.bairro, a.casa_numero, a.complemento,
a.celular, a.ped,a.ped_numero, a.emissao, a.entraga, a.vendedor, a.prazo,
a.transportador, a.total, a.obs, a.ativo,
b.codigo AS Codigo, b.prod, b.preco, b.qtd, b.und,
b.total AS Total,b.subtotal, b.numero AS Numero,
c.nome AS emp_nome, c.telefone AS emp_tel,
c.celular AS emp_cel, c.fax AS emp_fax,
c.endereco AS emp_end, c.web AS emp_web,
c.email AS emp_email
FROM pedidos a INNER JOIN
prod_pedidos b ON a.numero = b.numero, logos c
WHERE        (a.numero = @numero)
```

Comment: can you post some sample data?  it is possible that your join keys contain different values, hence no match

Comment: how's table logos connected to the other two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

**Conclusion:** use an inner join on your logo table instead of the comma, and add a condition for joining because you are at the moment doing a cartesian product.

---

However, since you don't have any result, it also means that there's no valid resultset for

```
(a.numero = @numero)
```

**Conclusion:** because you said you had datas in the tables:

- check that there's an actual `a.numero` corresponding to `@numero`
- check that you passed the correct parameter to `@numero`
- check that your parameter `@numero` implements the expected format of `a.numero`

Hope it helped,

S.

Comment: yes i have passed correct number before this query was working but after  adding third table 'logos' without error not retrieving data

Comment: are you sure there's a line in your table "logo" ?

Comment: YES IN LOGOS TABLE HAVE LINE

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be the join type - INNER JOIN returns data that is in both a and b tables. if data is only in a, or ony in b then it won't get returned. use LEFT or RIGHT join.

Also you need to somehow link to tables c - logos

```
SELECT a.id, a.numero, a.nome, a.codigo, a.fantasia, a.cnpj, a.endereco,
a.telefone, a.uf, a.cidade, a.cep, a.bairro, a.casa_numero, a.complemento,
a.celular, a.ped,a.ped_numero, a.emissao, a.entraga, a.vendedor, a.prazo,
a.transportador, a.total, a.obs, a.ativo,
b.codigo AS Codigo, b.prod, b.preco, b.qtd, b.und,
b.total AS Total,b.subtotal, b.numero AS Numero,
c.nome AS emp_nome, c.telefone AS emp_tel,
c.celular AS emp_cel, c.fax AS emp_fax,
c.endereco AS emp_end, c.web AS emp_web,
c.email AS emp_email
FROM pedidos a LEFT JOIN
prod_pedidos b ON a.numero = b.numero
LEFT JOIN logos c ON a.nome=c.nome
WHERE        (a.numero = @numero)
```